# My Page.ss wont load css and script SilverStripe v4.2.1

Tags: html, css, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have WAMP as my local server. I followed instructions carefully and i cant get my css and script loaded on my Page.ss. I flushed the cache and refresh the page and update the hrefs but none of them seem to have worked.

**Page.ss**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content= "">
<meta name="author" content= "Lisandro">
<meta name="keywords" content= "">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/u-mart/css/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/u-mart/css/slick- 
theme.css">       
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/u-mart/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
"TONS OF HTML CODES"
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is where my page.ss is located]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. All you have to do is add  these lines in your .SS file.

```
 <% require css("<my-module-dir>/css/some_file.css") %>
 <% require themedCSS("some_themed_file") %>
 <% require javascript("<my-module-dir>/javascript/some_file.js") %>
```

These were not mentioned on the lessons in their website neither on the videos. You will have to dig on your own.

Comment: Nice! The reason you need to do this is because the requirements API will resolve references that exist inside the `public/` subfolder (and `resources/` as well), whereas the `themes/` folder is not accessible directly via the web server. You should accept your answer as the correct solution, and even maybe make a pull request to clarify the lessons for future - it's all open source! https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-lessons-v4